# Python: Error code 1 when installing Numpy from Pip

Tags: python, numpy

I appreciate that there are several topics on the pip error code 1 but the solutions haven't worked and the question has ended.

I installed the full Python 3.4 package at work. I tried to use Pip to install the Numpy package but couldn't get past my works proxy. I downloaded Numpy and added the install file path to %PATH% and again tried to install using Pip but now I am getting 'Error Code 1'. I then tried to install the wheel as one Stack Overflow answer had suggested but still get 'Error Code 1'. I have also tried installing various versions of Numpy and successfully installed the latest version of Pip via Pip installer so I know the %PATH% and Pip install is good.

Python Version: 3.4
Pip Version: 7.1.2
Windows 7 64bit
Numpy Version: 1.10.1

Error:

Command "`C:\Python34\python.exe - c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MC364~1.BRA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-2kvveqqk-build\\setup.py';exec(cinouke(getattr(tokenize, 'open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MC364~1.BRA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-q_5tj3ef-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile`" failed with error coode 1 in C:\Users\MC364~1.BRA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2kvveqqk-build

Comment: Check [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for some precompiled windows binaries (`python pip install mypackage.whl` to install it), or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) if you are not familiar with python, it will be much easier than trying to install numpy using pip.

Comment: Hi Holt, thank you for your response. I tried installing the wheels from that site but got exactly the same error. Trying to avoid using Anaconda if I can, particularly as installing numpy via pip should be pretty straightforward.